# what is the importance of value attribute in request mappping of post method and this value is co-related in the project in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

i have a request mapping with post method but i do not know what i should put in value attribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String guestUserRegistration(@RequestHeader(value = "referer", required = false) final String referer,
        final RegisterForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model,
        final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final RedirectAttributes redirectModel)
        throws CMSItemNotFoundException
{
    logger.info("guest User post method::");
    return processGuestUserRequest(referer, form, bindingResult, model, request, response, redirectModel);
}
```

How the the "register" word as value is linked in spring mvc?

Answer (score 2):

The `HTTP` method parameter has no default – so if you don't specify a value, it's going to map to any HTTP request.

**@RequestMapping – by Path**

In your example, you are mapping a request by path i.e "/register".

**Request Mapping Basics**

In Spring MVC applications, the `RequestDispatcher` (i.e. Front Controller) servlet is responsible for routing incoming `HTTP` requests to handler methods of controllers. When configuring Spring MVC, you need to specify the mappings between the requests and handler methods.

**Test Mapping**

To execute this mapping you just need to call this endpoint from your registoer action button. All API endpoints are relative to the base URL.

For example, assuming the base URL of `https://api.example.com/`, the `/registor` endpoint refers to `https://api.example.com/registor`.

```
https://api.example.com/registor
\______________________/\____/
         server URL      endpoint path
```

Comment: but how to define in button click of submit it should redirect to the method